# Como finalizar a execução do código em Python 3?

Tags: python

```
print('Calcula raizes equação 2º grau')
a = float(input('Informe o Valor de A'))
while a == 0:
    print('a equação não é do segundo grau')
    break
b = float(input('Informe o Valor de B'))
c = float(input('Informe o Valor de C'))
delta = (b ** 2) - 4 * (a * c)
print(delta)
while delta < 0:
    print('A equação não possui raizes reais')
    break
if delta > 0:
    print('possui 2 raizes reais ')
    raizdelta = delta ** 0.5
    print('Raiz de delta',raizdelta)
    x1 = (-b + raizdelta) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - raizdelta) / (2 * a)
    print('x1',x1)
    print('x2',x2)
```

estou com problema quando a variável (a = 0) em vez de finalizar a execução do código ela continua... oq posso fazer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se o que deseja é encerrar a execução então deve usar um `exit()` e não um `break`. Na verdade deveria ser um `if` e não um `while` que não faz sentido aí. Se usasse dentro de uma função (que eu prefiro fazer sempre até para tirar a cara de *script* do código) então poderia só usar um `return` para encerrar.

A não ser que quisesse perguntar de novo, aí o `while` seria adequado, porém a lógica seria outra.

```
print('Calcula raizes equação 2º grau')
a = float(input('Informe o Valor de A'))
if a == 0:
    print('a equação não é do segundo grau')
    exit()
b = float(input('Informe o Valor de B'))
c = float(input('Informe o Valor de C'))
delta = (b ** 2) - 4 * (a * c)
print(delta)
if delta < 0:
    print('A equação não possui raizes reais')
    exit()
if delta > 0:
    print('possui 2 raizes reais ')
    raizdelta = delta ** 0.5
    print('Raiz de delta',raizdelta)
    x1 = (-b + raizdelta) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - raizdelta) / (2 * a)
    print('x1',x1)
    print('x2',x2)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8LLSYB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yvbsdbat-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ExitProgram.py).